# JS: передать результат ф-ций на textarea

Tags: javascript, html

**У меня есть 2 разных ф-ции и я хочу чтобы каждая выводилась на разную textarea.
1-я ф-ция:**

**Снизу поле с текстом куда хочу чтобы вывелась 1 ф-ция в моем случае это перетасованый текст**

```js
String.prototype.shuffle = function() {
  return this.split(" ").map(function(word, i) {
    var a = word.split(""),
      n = a.length;

    for (var i = n - 1; i > 0; i--) {
      var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
      var tmp = a[i];
      a[i] = a[j];
      a[j] = tmp;
    }

    return a.join("");
  }).join(" ");
}
console.log("Shuffled text".shuffle());
```

```html
<textarea class="usertext" id="result" cols="30" rows="5"></textarea>
```

**Снизу поле с текстом для 2 ф-ции(которая выводит массив)**

**2-я ф-ция:**

```js
let a = [
  ['п', 'е', 'р', 'е'],
  ['с', 'т', 'а', 'н'],
  ['о', 'в', 'к', 'и']
];
let b = trans(a);

function trans(m) {
  if (!m.length || !m[0].length) return;
  let r = m.length,
    c = m[0].length,
    t = new Array(c).fill().map(() => new Array(r));
  for (let y = 0; y < r; y++) {
    for (let x = 0; x < c; x++) {
      t[x][y] = m[y][x];
    }
  }
  return t;
}

output(a, b);

function output(...m) {
  if (!m.length || !m[0].length || !m[0][0].length) return;
  let n = m.length,
    r = Math.max(...m.map(m => m.length)),
    l = m.reduce((a, v, i) => (a += v[0].length + 3, a), 0),
    o = new Array(r).fill('');
  for (let y = 0; y < r; y++) {
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      for (let x = 0, c = m[i][y] ? m[i][y].length : m[i][0].length; x < c; x++) {
        o[y] += (m[i][y] ? m[i][y][x] : ' ') + ' ';
      }
      o[y] += i < n - 1 ? '   |    ' : '';
    }
  }
  console.log(o.join `\n`);
}
```

```html
<textarea class="text" id="result" cols="30" rows="7"></textarea>
```

Comment: а в чем проблема задайте id  result1 и result2 и value для каждого

Comment: я понимаю о чем вы, но у меня 2 страницы поэтому написал 2 textarea, у меня просто проблемы с самим выводом этих резалтов потому, что новенький в js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не стану доставать result1 и result2. Поскольку они в dom.

```js
String.prototype.shuffle = function() {
  return this.split(" ").map(function(word, i) {
    var a = word.split(""),
      n = a.length;

    for (var i = n - 1; i > 0; i--) {
      var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
      var tmp = a[i];
      a[i] = a[j];
      a[j] = tmp;
    }

    return a.join("");
  }).join(" ");
}
result1.value = "Shuffled text".shuffle();

//-----++++----

let a = [
  ['п', 'е', 'р', 'е'],
  ['с', 'т', 'а', 'н'],
  ['о', 'в', 'к', 'и']
];
let b = trans(a);

function trans(m) {
  if (!m.length || !m[0].length) return;
  let r = m.length,
    c = m[0].length,
    t = new Array(c).fill().map(() => new Array(r));
  for (let y = 0; y < r; y++) {
    for (let x = 0; x < c; x++) {
      t[x][y] = m[y][x];
    }
  }
  return t;
}

output(a, b);

function output(...m) {
  if (!m.length || !m[0].length || !m[0][0].length) return;
  let n = m.length,
    r = Math.max(...m.map(m => m.length)),
    l = m.reduce((a, v, i) => (a += v[0].length + 3, a), 0),
    o = new Array(r).fill('');
  for (let y = 0; y < r; y++) {
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      for (let x = 0, c = m[i][y] ? m[i][y].length : m[i][0].length; x < c; x++) {
        o[y] += (m[i][y] ? m[i][y][x] : ' ') + ' ';
      }
      o[y] += i < n - 1 ? '   |    ' : '';
    }
  }
  result2.value = o.join( `\n`);
}
```

```html
<textarea class="usertext" id="result1" cols="30" rows="5"></textarea> 
<textarea class="usertext" id="result2" cols="30" rows="5"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById("result").value = output(a, b);` И заменил внутри функции output() console.log на return. Но по определению, у HTML элементов не должны быть одинаковые id, заменил и их:

```js
String.prototype.shuffle = function() {
  return this.split(" ").map(function(word, i) {
    var a = word.split(""), len = a.length;

    for (var i = len - 1; i > 0; i--) {
      var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
      
      var tmp = a[i];
      a[i] = a[j];
      a[j] = tmp;
    }

    return a.join("");
  }).join(" ");
}

/***/

let a = [
  ['п', 'е', 'р', 'е'],
  ['с', 'т', 'а', 'н'],
  ['о', 'в', 'к', 'и']
];
let b = trans(a);

function trans(m) {
  if (!m.length || !m[0].length) return;
  let r = m.length,
    c = m[0].length,
    t = new Array(c).fill().map(() => new Array(r));
  for (let y = 0; y < r; y++) {
    for (let x = 0; x < c; x++) {
      t[x][y] = m[y][x];
    }
  }
  return t;
}

function output(...m) {
  // Какая-то нечитаемая функция. Поверим, что она работает.
  if (!m.length || !m[0].length || !m[0][0].length) return;
  let n = m.length,
    r = Math.max(...m.map(m => m.length)),
    l = m.reduce((a, v, i) => (a += v[0].length + 3, a), 0),
    o = new Array(r).fill('');
    
  for (let y = 0; y < r; y++) {
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      for (let x = 0, c = m[i][y] ? m[i][y].length : m[i][0].length; x < c; x++) {
        o[y] += (m[i][y] ? m[i][y][x] : ' ') + ' ';
      }
      o[y] += i < n - 1 ? '   |    ' : '';
    }
  }
  
  return o.join("\n"); // <-- заменил console.log() на return;
}

/***/

document.getElementById("area-1").value = output(a, b);
document.getElementById("area-2").value = "Shuffled text".shuffle();
```

```html
<textarea id="area-1" cols="30" rows="5"></textarea>
<hr>
<textarea id="area-2" cols="30" rows="7"></textarea>
```

Можно написать и общую функцию, которая будет привязывать результат функции к элементу:

```js
function bind_to_element(selector, fn) {
  let elem = document.querySelector(selector);
  let value = ["TEXTAREA", "INPUT"].includes(elem.tagName) ? "value" : "textContent";

  return function() {
    // Создается новая функция, которая будет вызвана вместо исходной fn()
    // arguments - список аргументов, полученных при вызове этой функции.

    // Сама возвращает результат вызова переданной функции fn(),
    // между делом записывает этот же результат в HTML элемент.

    return elem[value] = fn.apply(null, arguments);
  }
}

let test_1 = bind_to_element("#a", function(a, b) {
  // Вот эта функция привязывается к элементу id="a";
  // И вызывается под именем test_1
  return a + b;
});

let test_2 = bind_to_element("#b", function(a, b) {
  return a * b;
});

console.log( test_1(10, 10) );
console.log( test_2(10, 10) );

// в вашем случае можно использовать это как 
// output = bind_to_element("#result", output);
```

```html
<p id="a"></p>
<textarea id="b"></textarea>
```